# Why cStringUsingEncoding: returns const char * instead of char *?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, constants

cStringUsingEncoding: returns a "const char *" despite it is returning a dynamically allocated C string(from it's documentation). So, what is the purpose of const here? We could simply modify the returned C string by casting to char *.

> **cStringUsingEncoding:**
>
> The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the
>   receiver is freed, or until the current autorelease pool is emptied,
>   whichever occurs first.

I think library is following the common practice of pointer-to-const; it's not expected to be modified or released.

> **From Objective-C runtime;**
>
> **const char *** object_getClassName(id obj) -- Nothing specified about the returned string.
>
> **char *** method_copyArgumentType(Method method, unsigned int index) -- You must free the string with free(). (May be it's advising because of it's returning a copy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common pattern is that you should not modify buffers that you don't own. `const` documents and (somewhat) enforces this.

As for `cStringUsingEncoding:`, The documentation is saying that the returned buffer is only valid as long as the NSString from which you received it, or for the duration of the current autorelease pool. This implies that you *do not* own the returned buffer, because you're not expected to release it.

Your last two examples from the runtime follow the same convention:

- `const char * object_getClassName(id obj)`

  Doesn't inform you that you should release the buffer, and the name doesn't contain any indication that you own the buffer. Therefore you don't `free()` it, and you don't modify it.
- `char * method_copyArgumentType(Method method, unsigned int index)`

  The docs explicitly tell you that you should free the buffer, and the function name contains the tell-tale `copy` which also implies that you own the buffer. Therefore you can modify it all you want, and must `free()` it.

Comment: so it is about const correctness; modifiability and mostly ownership, am i right?

Comment: Yes, the code is const correct, according to its modifiability, as determined by its ownership.

Comment: But how do we conclude about modifiability from ownership?(if we are talking about memory mngmnt rules there is no relation between modifiability and ownership afaik.)

Comment: Exposing a raw buffer like that while allowing for its modification breaks encapsulation, because the buffer could be changed from outside the implementation of the owner. While its technically possible, it's not desirable. That code is making the immutability explicit with the const.

Comment: Ok. So we may not know if it's using the same buffer as the internal representation and allowing it's modification would break encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

Thing is, the result is const because

- modifying it will not change the string itself, and the cString is really just meant to be a different representation of the string
- it will probably return the same cString "over and over again", as long as the string doesn't change.

Other than that, declaring a result to be const even if the implementation doesn't enforce or require that is something an interface designer can do, maybe because he wants it to be treated that way. And it leaves the path open to optimize things for cases where the "const" is useful.

Comment: For the first option, we comprehend from the doco and method signature that cstring is a different representation but if method is called with same encoding of internal representation(or for some other reason) then it might return the reference of internal NSString buffer. thus it must be conceptually unmodifiable,right?

Comment: what do you actually want to mean with this: "modifying it will not change the string itself, and the cString is really just meant to be a different representation of the string" ? it's only meaningful when we consider it with your next statement. otherwise, when we consider it alone we may ask: if it's a different representation why does it need to be const?